# Unable to publish the code coverage result into Sonar Cloud Dashboard

Tags: .net, azure-devops, .net-framework-version, sonarcloud

I have on .Net Framework Application, tried to publish the code coverage result into Sonar Cloud Dashboard, but unable to publish the code coverage result
Using YAML File
Task - VSTest & Codecoverage.exe

Reference YAML File

```
pool:    
    ${{ if ne(parameters.AgentImage, '') }}:
      vmImage: '${{parameters.AgentImage}}' 
    ${{ else }}:
        name: SelfhostedAgent
        demands:
        - vstest
        - msbuild
        - visualstudio
        - java
  
  workspace:
    clean: all

  steps:
  - checkout: self
    clean: true

  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.x'
    inputs:
     versionSpec: 4.x
     checkLatest: true

  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: 'Restore NuGet Packages Service'
    inputs:
      restoreSolution: '${{ parameters.serviceSolution }}'
      feedsToUse: config
      nugetConfigPath: '${{ parameters.NugetserviceSolution }}'
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.SolutionCustomPath }}', ''))

  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: 'Restore NuGet Packages Presentation'
    inputs:
      restoreSolution: '${{ parameters.PresentationSolution }}'
      feedsToUse: config
      nugetConfigPath: '${{ parameters.NugetPresentationSolution }}'
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.SolutionCustomPath }}', ''))

  - task: SonarSource.sonarcloud.14d9cde6-c1da-4d55-aa01-2965cd301255.SonarCloudPrepare@1
    displayName: 'Prepare analysis on SonarCloud'
    inputs:
      SonarCloud: SonarCloud
      organization: msc
      projectKey: ${{ parameters.SonarProjectKey }}
      projectName: ${{ parameters.SonarProjectName }}
      extraProperties: |
        sonar.exclusions= ${{ parameters.SonarExclusions }}
        sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResult\*.trx
        sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResult\newCodeReport.coveragexml
        sonar.verbose=true

  - task: VSBuild@1
    displayName: 'Build solution ${{ parameters.PresentationSolution }}'
    inputs:
      solution: ${{ parameters.PresentationSolution }}
      msbuildArgs: '/p:OutDir=$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/Presentation'
      platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
      clean: true
      msbuildArchitecture: x64
      logProjectEvents: false
      maximumCpuCount: true
      vsVersion: ${{ parameters.VsVersion }}

  - task: VSBuild@1
    displayName: 'Build service solution'
    inputs:
      solution: '${{ parameters.serviceSolution }}'
      msbuildArgs: '/p:OutDir=$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/Service /p:RunCodeAnalysis=false /p:CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors=false'
      platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
      maximumCpuCount: true
      msbuildArchitecture: x64
      clean: true
      vsVersion: ${{ parameters.VsVersion }}

  - task: VSTest@2
    displayName: 'Unit Tests'
    inputs:
      testSelector: testAssemblies
      testAssemblyVer2: |
        **\Msc.*Test.dll
        !**\*TestAdapter.dll
        !**\obj\**  
      searchFolder: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/'
      codeCoverageEnabled: true
      resultsFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResult\'
      diagnosticsEnabled: true
      runOnlyImpactedTests: '${{ parameters.RunonlyTest}}'
      runInParallel: true
      rerunFailedTests: true
      testRunTitle: 'Unit Testing service layer'
      platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
      vsTestVersion: ${{ parameters.VsVersion }}
      
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        # Write your PowerShell commands here.
        Write-Host "Hello World"
        
        Get-ChildItem -Path "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResult\*" -Include *.coverage -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResult\" -verbose

        (Get-ChildItem -Path "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResult\" -Filter *.coverage).FullName | Rename-Item -NewName AgentName.coverage -verbose

        CodeCoverage analyze /output:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResult\newCodeReport.coveragexml $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\TestResult\AgentName.coverage
    continueOnError: true            

  - task: SonarSource.sonarcloud.ce096e50-6155-4de8-8800-4221aaeed4a1.SonarCloudAnalyze@1
    displayName: 'Run Code Analysis'
    
  - task: SonarSource.sonarcloud.38b27399-a642-40af-bb7d-9971f69712e8.SonarCloudPublish@1
    displayName: 'Publish Quality Gate Result'
```

I have tried to run the YAML File - Build was succeed, but code coverage results unable to publish in Sonar Cloud Dashboard

[SonarCloud Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NqoH.png)

[Pipeline RunCode Analysis task to Find out .coveragexml File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZH27.png)

[Code Coverage Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD6Nf.png)

Question is: If Codecovearge.exe is deprecated in SonarQube or SonarCloud. If any alternative way to publish the code coverage result into Sonar Cloud Dashboard

Comment: Hi @sudalai muthukumar, have you tried the suggestion below? Whether it works after removing "reportsPaths" from `extraProperties`, and add `scannerMode: 'MSBuild'` to SonarCloudPrepare@1 task?

Comment: Yes it was working after remove the report path. Thanks @ZiyangLiu-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested from my side, the code coverage result can be published to Sonar Cloud without any issue when using VSTest task. Below is my yaml file for your reference. You can try to remove reportsPaths from `extraProperties`, and add `scannerMode: 'MSBuild'` to `SonarCloudPrepare@1` task.

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '...'

- task: SonarCloudPrepare@1
  inputs:
    SonarCloud: 'SonarCloudConsoleAppFramework'
    organization: '{SonarCloud Org name}'
    scannerMode: 'MSBuild'
    projectKey: '{projectKey}'
    projectName: '{SonarCloud project name}'
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**\*.sln'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArchitecture: 'x64'
  
- task: VSTest@3
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    resultsFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)\TestResults'
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
  
- task: SonarCloudAnalyze@1
  inputs:
    jdkversion: 'JAVA_HOME_17_X64'

- task: SonarCloudPublish@1
  inputs:
    pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

The result in Sonar Cloud:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, it was working. The issue is not on task or YAML File, Permission issue on Sonar Cloud

Comment: Thanks for sharing the root cause with us. Would you please let us know the specific permissions in Sonar Cloud? This can help others who may have the same problem as you in the further.

Comment: Sorry for delay reply. Access Permission, now it was resolved with help of admin Team.