# Unable to Publish Code Coverage Report into Sonar Cloud. Use of OpenCover.Console.exe and Vstest.console.exe

Tags: azure-devops, .net-framework-version, opencover, sonarcloud, vstest.console.exe

Use of .Net Framework Application. I have tried to publish the code coverage result into Sonar Cloud Dashboard, but unable to publish the code coverage Report. Use of OpenCover.Console.exe + Vstest.console.exe

Please Refer the YAML File:

```
steps:
  - checkout: self
    clean: true

  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.x'
    inputs:
     versionSpec: 4.x
     checkLatest: true

# Nuget restore for Service and presentation layer
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: 'NuGet restore for service'
    inputs:
      restoreSolution: '${{ parameters.servicenugetSolution }}'
      feedsToUse: config
      nugetConfigPath: ${{ parameters.ServicenugetPath }}
    condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq('${{ parameters.Service }}', 'true'), eq('${{ parameters.ServiceandPresentation }}', 'true')) )

  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: 'NuGet restore for Presentation'
    inputs:
      restoreSolution: ${{ parameters.presentationSolution }}
      feedsToUse: config
      nugetConfigPath: ${{ parameters.presentationnugetPath }}
    condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq('${{ parameters.Presentation }}', 'true'), eq('${{ parameters.ServiceandPresentation }}', 'true')) )
     
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: 'NuGet restore for Solution'
    inputs:
       restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
       feedsToUse: config
       nugetConfigPath: ${{ parameters.presentationnugetPath }}
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.nugetRestoreAllSolutions }}', 'yes'))

# Sonar cloud for Service and presentation layer
  - task: SonarSource.sonarcloud.14d9cde6-c1da-4d55-aa01-2965cd301255.SonarCloudPrepare@1
    displayName: 'Prepare analysis on SonarCloud'
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne('${{ parameters.SonarProjectKey }}', ''), or(eq('${{ parameters.Presentation }}', 'true'), eq('${{ parameters.Service }}', 'true'), eq('${{ parameters.ServiceandPresentation }}', 'true')))
    inputs:
      SonarCloud: SonarCloud
      organization: msc
      projectKey: ${{ parameters.SonarProjectKey }}
      projectName: ${{ parameters.SonarProjectName }}
      extraProperties: |
        sonar.exclusions=${{ parameters.SonarExclusions }}
        sonar.dotnet.excludeTestProjects=true
        sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CoverageResults.xml

# Service Solution Build
  - task: VSBuild@1
    displayName: 'Build solution ${{ parameters.serviceSolution }}'
    inputs:
      solution: ${{ parameters.serviceSolution }}
      msbuildArgs: '/p:OutDir=$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/Service /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true'
      platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
      clean: true
      msbuildArchitecture: x64
      logProjectEvents: false
      maximumCpuCount: true
      vsVersion: ${{ parameters.VsVersion }}
    condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq('${{ parameters.Service }}', 'true'), eq('${{ parameters.ServiceandPresentation }}', 'true')) )

# Presentation Solution Build
  - task: VSBuild@1
    displayName: 'Build solution ${{ parameters.presentationSolution }}'
    inputs:
      solution: ${{ parameters.presentationSolution }}
      msbuildArgs: '/p:OutDir=$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/Presentation'
      platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
      clean: true
      msbuildArchitecture: x64
      logProjectEvents: false
      maximumCpuCount: true
      vsVersion: ${{ parameters.VsVersion }}
    condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq('${{ parameters.Presentation }}', 'true'), eq('${{ parameters.ServiceandPresentation }}', 'true')) )

  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Execute Code Coverage'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        get-location

        Echo "LocationPath:" $(Build.BinariesDirectory)
        Set-Location -Path $(Build.BinariesDirectory)

        $getSrcdirectory = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"

        $OpenCover = "E:\Software\opencover.4.7.1221\OpenCover.Console.exe"
        $ReportGenerator = "$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\reportgenerator.exe"

        &$OpenCover -register:user -target:"vstest.console.exe" -targetargs:".\service\SampleWork.Api.Test.dll" -output:"$($getSrcdirectory)\CoverageResults.xml"
 
# Run Code Analysis &Publish Quality Gate Result
  - task: SonarSource.sonarcloud.ce096e50-6155-4de8-8800-4221aaeed4a1.SonarCloudAnalyze@1
    displayName: 'Run Code Analysis'
    condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq('${{ parameters.Presentation }}', 'true'), eq('${{ parameters.Service }}', 'true'), eq('${{ parameters.ServiceandPresentation }}', 'true')) )
```

I have try to trigger on YAML Pipeline it was working fine. The task execution details are..

1. Use OpenCover.console.ex - To created the Coverage XML File in that Specified Path.[image: OpenCoverConsole Execution Log]
2. Run Code Analysis - It also pickup the Code Coverage File [image: Run Code Analysis Log]

Final Report Is: Code Coverage report was not publish in Sonar Cloud Dashboard [image: Sonar Cloud Dashboard Log]

Question Is: Use of OpenConsole.exe and Vstest.console.exe to Publish the Code Coverage Result into Dashboard

Comment: Hi, I noticed that you asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77696098/unable-to-publish-the-code-coverage-result-into-sonar-cloud-dashboard?rq=2) before. In that question, you said you can publish the code coverage result into Sonar Cloud Dashboard after resolving a permission issue.   Has anything changed since then?

Comment: Hi Miao, 
No permission issue, because i have tried to Covertlet Console to publish result into Sonar Cloud it was succeeded. Same way i have tried on OpenCover.Console but it did not work.

Comment: Hi Sudalai, thanks for your explanation. I found two similar cases about Code Coverage 0% with OpenCover (the [issue one](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/c-code-coverage-0-opencover/52408) and [issue two](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarcloud-msbuild-code-opencover-coverage-issue/40752/2)). They solved the issues by running against the right branch. Can you check your branch setting?